# Pull-to-refresh modifies array value?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I'm working on a pull-to-refresh on iOS with Swift.
I have an array with city names, `cityNames = ["Chicago", "New York City"]`
I implemented a pull-to-refresh to fetch temperature data from the internet.  So every time I trigger the pull-to-refresh, it will go to the internet and get the temperature for each city in the `cityNames` array.
Here is the code for pull-to-refresh

```
var weatherDetail = [Weather]()
// Pull to refresh
func refreshData() {
    var cityNames = [String]()
    for (index, _) in weatherDetail.enumerate() {
        let info = weatherDetail[index]
        cityNames.append(info.cityName)
    }
    print(cityNames)
    weatherDetail.removeAll()
    for city in cityNames {
        self.forwardGeocoding(city)
    }
    weatherCityTable.reloadData()
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

In the code above, `weatherDetail` is a array of model(I'm not sure how to phrase this, but `Weather` is a model, which contains city names, temperature, sun rise time, high/low temperature.
`forwardGeocoding` is a function that get the geo coordination for a city then sends a request to get the weather data for that city.
The pull-to-refresh works, the issue I'm encountering is, for the first 2,3 times when I pull, it works with no problem.  But as I pull more times, the array will suddenly change to `cityNames = ["Chicago", "Chicago"]`
Thank you for your help, please let me know if you need more information.

UPDATE:
I removed `weatherDetail.removeAll()`, try to just append the same data to the array. After the refresh, it prints out `"Chicago", "New York City", "Chicago", "Chicago"`. If I refresh it more times, it prints out something like `"Chicago", "New York City", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago"`

Comment: The cityNames array is not in your code. How is it filled?

Comment: @Darko Thank you for point that out, just modified the code.

Comment: One issue which is visible from the given code: you are just appending to cityNames but never delete it.

Comment: Maybe you try to refresh while is refreshing? so, maybe adding a var isRefreshing and just update if it is not updating.

Comment: What populates the weatherDetail array?

Comment: How the `weatherDetail` array is populating? Is it populating inside the `forwardGeocoding` method because `weatherDetail.removeAll()` is removing all the data from array for the next pull to refresh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is forwardGeocoding synchronous?
When does weatherDetail get set/updated?

It looks to me like you have some sort of synchronicity issue going on here, probably exacerbated by latency.

Answer (score 4):

Using `enumerate()` and `append()` to do this is not a good approach ,there is a more elegance and error-proof way to achieve this:

```
let cityNames:[String] = weatherDetail.map { weather -> String in
     weather.cityName
}
```

Or just write:

```
let cityNames:[String] = weatherDetail.map { $0.cityName }
```

Answer (score 3):

If city names are repeated twice, that means that information in `weatherDetail` array is repeated twice too. Try printing `weatherDetail` before printing `cityNames`. If `weatherDetail` is repeated twice, then you should locate the code that adds the same `Weather` objects twice and eliminate it.

For testing purposes, locate every place that modifies `weatherDetail`, and before those statements put `weatherDetail.removeAll()`. If that removes your problem, then search for the code that adds redundant info to `weatherDetail`.

Comment: The issue is not the city names are repeated twice, it got replaced to the same value.

Comment: Did you try printing `weatherDetail` before `cityNames`? Does it contain the same `Weather` info in all elements? Did you test your bug on an array with 5-10 objects? `cityNames` is just a result of mapping `weatherDetail`, so I'm pretty sure you have repeating values in your `weatherDetail`, and that's the root of all evil.

Comment: Since `weatherDetail` is made with a model, when I print it out, all I got is `[<JWeather.Weather: 0x7fc3b346b540>, <JWeather.Weather: 0x7fc3b346ae00>]`.  When I test it with 5-10 objects, the array will become `["Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "New York", "New York", "Washington", "Washington", "Washington", "Beijing"]` While I originally put in 9 different cities.

Comment: print in a loop `weather.cityName`, something like this: `for weatherInfo in weatherDetail { print(weatherInfo.cityName) }` . If you see repeating values, then the trouble is in your weatherDetail array and you should try to find where you put the same values again and again.

Comment: When I print it out, I got different city names, no repeating value.  I used `for weather in weatherDetail {
            print(weather.cityName)
        }`.  Therefore, it means the original loop contains error.  At least it provides me a direction.

Comment: Is the implementation of refreshData() complete? I'm 99% sure that it's impossible for cityNames to contain different city names. Could you please try this piece of code right in the beginning of method: http://pastebin.com/L6WL6MjX . If the content of print is different, then I'm 99% sure you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I put the piece of code in the beginning of the method, I got the following `New York
Chicago
Los Angles
Mosco
Albany
["New York", "Chicago", "Los Angles", "Mosco", "Albany"]`

Comment: Okay, now please replace your function with this one http://pastebin.com/LeuyS9wa . If that doesn't help, I give up.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I appreciate that.  I put the code in, here is the result. `["New York", "Chicago", "Los Angles", "Mosco", "Albany"]
["Los Angles", "Los Angles", "Los Angles", "Los Angles", "Los Angles"]
`  When I refresh it for the first time, it changed from 5 different cities to all LA, but still prints the 5 different cities. Then I refreshed it for the second time, it print all LA.

Comment: Now I am 100% sure that weatherDetail simply contains the same cities. If you show me the full code of your view controller, I might be able to spot your bug.

Comment: https://github.com/qi1f/JWeather/blob/master/JWeather/JWeather/ViewController.swift   This is the vie controller.

Comment: There's a very suspicious method `setWeather(weather: Weather)` which is the only place that modifies your weatherDetail. I'd look for the bug there. I give up, I'll just go to sleep.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks anyway.